# Find the nth power of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Let matrix A is

$$A=\left (\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0 \\
1&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right)$$

How can I find the 30 th power of A.. 
Is diagonalization possible?

I found the eigen values But cannot continue.

Comment: The trace of your matrix is $3$, so most surely your eigenvalues cannot be $1,1,-1$ (as their sum is $1$)...

Comment: Yea,  I must have confused with sone other question..

Comment: I would edit your question, then

Answer (score 4):

Notice that
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  a & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  b & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
  a+b & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \quad
 \text{for all $a,b \in K$},
$$
where $K$ denotes the ground field. Therefore
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}^n
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  n & 1
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now notice that your matrix is a block matrix of the form
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 &   \\
  1 & 1 &   \\
    &   & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  A &   \\
    & B
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
with
$$
 A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 B = (1).
$$

Therefore
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 &   \\
  1 & 1 &   \\
    &   & 1
 \end{pmatrix}^n
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  A &   \\
    & B
 \end{pmatrix}^n
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  A^n &   \\
      & B^n
 \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 &   \\
  n & 1 &   \\
    &   & 1
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

PS: Alternatively one can realize that your matrix is an elementary matrix, namely the one adding the fist row to the second. Applying this $n$-times is the same as just adding the first row $n$-times to the second, which is represented by the matrix we calculated.

Comment: Very nice. I like the use of block matrices.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to calculate the first terms and see if there's a pattern.
$$
A^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
2&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
A^3=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
3&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Maybe you should try to prove using induction that
$$
A^{n}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
n&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$