# Find the 30th power of a matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ be the following matrix:
>   $$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
> 1&0&0\\
> 1&0&1\\
> 0&1&0\\
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
>   Find the matrix $A^{30}$.

Is this matrix diagonalizable? Is there any other method to find the higher power, when the matrix cannot be diagonalized?

Comment: it can be solved by eigen vectors

Comment: You could always resort to successive squaring, if all else fails…but that is a bit tedious…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the nth power of a matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606925/find-the-nth-power-of-a-matrix)

Comment: @amd: How is this a duplicate? The matrices in the two questions are different, both in details and in kind. The other matrix is an elementary matrix, while this one is not. It is a permutation matrix with an elementary operation applied, but that is not the same.

Comment: @RoryDaulton oops. You’re right. I misread this one and jumped the gun because the two questions were from the same person and of a similar nature.

Comment: What will be the eigan vector

Comment: Use Cayley Hamilton relationship, here $A^3=A^2+A-I$ which allows a gradual degree diminishing

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Prove by induction that:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
\end{array}\right) ^{2n}=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0\\
n&1&0\\
n&0&1\\
\end{array}\right) 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
\end{array}\right) 
= \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0\\
1&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
\end{array}\right) 
$$
decomposes as two elementary matrices.

Comment: Then what is the next step

Comment: Since they are elementary matrices, they correspond to row/column ops. So raising it to the $30$-th power, or any power, corresponds to doing this set of operations 30 times.